# SimpleXML - Array appears to be missing some attributes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm using SimpleXML to parse XML data from a web-service. Everything has gone well up to this point, but I'm now finding myself stumped. I'm finding that the array produced by SimpleXML appears to be missing some attributes. I'm hoping that I'm making a simple mistake, and would really appreciate the input.

Sample XML Data:

```
<XYZ data-livestyle-extension="available">
 <year selected="2016">
  <make selected="Alfa Romeo">
   <model selected="4C">
    <submodel vehiclecd="20180">Base</submodel>
    <submodel vehiclecd="20181">Launch Edition</submodel>
    <submodel vehiclecd="20182">Track Package</submodel>
   </model>
  </make>
 </year>
</XYZ>
```

My PHP:

```
$xmlURL = "http://www.domain.com/submodels.xml";
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dataset = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);

foreach($dataset as $data) {
  foreach($data->make->model->submodel as $submodel) {
    var_dump($submodel);
  }
  die();
}
```

Results from the var_dump:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  ["@attributes"]=>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  array(1) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    ["vehiclecd"]=>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    string(5) "20180"                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) {                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  ["@attributes"]=>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  array(1) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    ["vehiclecd"]=>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    string(5) "20181"                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) {                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  ["@attributes"]=>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  array(1) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    ["vehiclecd"]=>                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    string(5) "20182"                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  [0]=>                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  string(13) "Track Package"                                                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

I don't know why the string "Track Package" is available for the third instance, but the "Launch Edition" and "Base" strings are excluded. I'm basically trying to get two values from each instance of the submodel node...

- The value of the node (eg: 'Base')
- The value of "vehiclecd"

I was really hoping to resolve this on my own, but have been unable to do so. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: replacing `var_dump()` with `echo $submodel->asXML();` will give you more detail.

Comment: Thank you so much, @michi! Once I did that, I could see that everything was as I expected it to be! My code was correct all along, but the var_dump was misleading. :-)

Comment: Yep. SimpleXML does not produce an array; it doesn't even really exist as an object, in the sense that `var_dump` expects. Think of it as a bunch of methods for accessing your XML, and you'll be less surprised by what it seems to "contain".